# Connecting localhost sql database with OLEDB

Tags: mysql, vb.net, connection-string

I have the following code to connect the localhost database with OLEDB using VB.NET. Below are the code:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Module Module1
Public conn As OleDbConnection

Public Sub OpenConnection()

    conn = New OleDbConnection()

    If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then

        Try
        conn.ConnectionString = "provider=MySQLProv; Data Source=mydbname; User Id=root; Password=password"

         conn.Open()

            MsgBox("Connected to DB")

Catch ex As OleDbException
                MessageBox.Show("Error Connecting to Database")
                conn.Close()
                conn.Dispose()
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub
```

When running, the error "The 'MySQLProv' provider is not registered on the local machine." appears. I already installed MySQL Connector Net 6.5.7 and MySQL Connector ODBC 5.3 but Visual Studios says it is not installed.

I also have tried different connection string as below but each of them has error:

```
            'conn.ConnectionString = "Driver={MySQL};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=smsengine5;USER=root;PASSWORD=password"

            'conn.ConnectionString = "provider=MYSQLOLEDB; Driver={MySQL};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=mydbname;USER=root;PASSWORD=password"

            'conn.ConnectionString = "provider=.NET Framework Data Provider for MySQL;*;Uid=root;Pwd=password;Database=mydbname;"

            'conn.ConnectionString = "provider=MySQLProv; Data Source=mydbname; User Id=root; Password=password"

            'conn.ConnectionString = "Driver={mysql};Server=localhost;PORT=3306;UI D=root;PWD=password;OPTION=16386"

            'conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=<<MySQLProv>>; Location=<<localhost>>; Data Source=<<mydbname>>; USER ID=<<root>>; PASSWORD=<<password>>; option=3;port=33 06;"

            'conn.ConnectionString = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=localhost Database=mydbname; User=root; Password=password; Optio n=4;"

            'conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=MySQLProv.3.9;Location=<<localhost>>;Data Source=<<mydbname>>; USER ID=<<>root>>;Password=<<password>>;port=<<3306>>;"

            'conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=MySQL Provider; Data Source=localhost; User ID=root; Password=password; Initial Catalog=mydbname;"

            'conn.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=mydbname;Uid=User;Pwd=mypass; providerName=MySql.Data.MySqlClient"

            'conn.ConnectionString = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=mydbname; User=root;Password=myPassword;Option=3;"

            'conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=localhost; Initial Catalog=mydbname; User ID=root; Password=password;"

            'conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost:3306;Database=mydbname;User ID=root; Password=password;"
```

I also done referencing Mysql.Data in my project.

**I do not want to use MySQL Client.

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are three connection strings for MySQL using OLEDB as stated [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/):

**Standard**

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
MySQL
```

**Specifying TCP port**

```
Server=myServerAddress;Port=1234;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;
Pwd=myPassword;
```

The port 3306 is the default MySql port.The value is ignored if Unix socket is used.

**Multiple servers**

Use this to connect to a server in a replicated server configuration without concern on which server to use.

```
Server=serverAddress1, serverAddress2, serverAddress3;Database=myDataBase;
Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

Comment: Tried the first one and second one, error message:
"An OLE DB Provider was not specified in the ConnectionString.  An example would be, 'Provider=SQLOLEDB;'."

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using "provider = MSDataShape"